# Limiting the size of system.log and exception.log files

Tags: log, server-setup

I was trying to troubleshoot a problem on my site and went to look at the `system.log` file and it was over 1GB.

The `exception.log` wasn't as big but it got me thinking:

How do you limit the size of the logging files for Magento?

Comment: i think through cron job you can clear log periodically.there will be settings in the admin.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate

Follow this i think it will help you to solve your issue :-

```
cd /etc/logrotate.d/
vim magento-logrotate.conf
```

now add the following to the `magento-logrotate.conf` file:

```
/path/to/magento/var/log/*log {
rotate 7
daily
compress
missingok
notifempty
}
```

execute your configuration now:

```
logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/magento-logrotate.conf
```

Comment: I really like this approach, will try it out and accept after a few days provided it works (it should) or that someone doesnt come up with a better answer.

Comment: Do a cronjob required to run it daily? @Manish Kumar

Answer (score 1):

The most interesting is: **what is in your log files?**

Generally, the log files contain notifications, warnings and errors. When I have finished building a Magento webshop or a new module, one of my personal requirements is to have nothing appear in the logs when running/using this shop or module. If something would appear, then something should be improved (notices) or is terribly wrong (errors).

To answer your question of how to limit the size of `system.log` and `exception.log` files: fix the problems that are described in those files. These files aren't there for nothing.

B.t.w. `logrotate` ([suggested](//magento.stackexchange.com/a/95489/3326) by Manish Kumar) is a great thing too ;)

Answer (score 0):

> add new line below to the

```
$file = empty($file) ? 'system.log' : $file;
$file = date('Ymd').$file;
```

[image]

Comment: very stupid idea...

Comment: I can't find this "stupid". It's a hack, but ho-hum.

Comment: I agree this is a stupid idea, unless you would add to your answer how to do this WITHOUT EDITING CORE FILES and you should add a method to clean up "old" log files (for instance with a Bash script that deletes files with a date prefix of X days old...