# how to empty .log file in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, exception, log

how to empty `.log` file in Magento 2 from **Terminal** ?

- system.log
- exceptional.log
- debug.log

Comment: Usually logs are generated by themselves, you can simply run rm -rf var/log/* That will delete the logs files, and then you whenever you load any page which has exception logs, these will be created

Comment: > var/log/debug.log

Comment: please add as answer :) @Robert_Szczepaniec

Answer (score 4):

To empty log files you have to run below command from the command line

```
> system.log
> exception.log
> debug.log
```

Remember you need to be in var directory before run the above command.
Also you can always delete the files and magento will auto generate them.

Answer (score 3):

You can remove the log files from terminal using below command, it will not create any issue as log files again generated in var/log;

```
rm -rf magento_root/var/log/*;
```

For removing log files everyday i suggest create a cron on server using below code:

```
0 0 * * 0-6 cd /magento_root/; rm -rf var/log/*
```

Above cron will run everyday at 12:00 AM.
Let me know if this is not working.

Answer (score 3):

As the other answers have pointed out, since the logs are autogenerated removing them should be fine. Although this will override any permission etc you set on the files.

If you are purley looking to empty the file you can use the truncate command.

```sh
truncate -s0 /var/www/site.com/var/log/exception.log
```

---

As a side note, if you are wanting to periodically empty logs. Then i would recommend setting up and configuring `LogRotate`. This will allow you to compress the old logs and store them for a set amount of time before scrapping them.

See the following thread on using LogRotate [Limiting the size of system.log and exception.log files](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95488/limiting-the-size-of-system-log-and-exception-log-files)

Answer (score 1):

```
> var/log/debug.log
> var/log/system.log
> var/log/exception.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove those files. Then it will generate again Automatically

ca var/log/
sudo rm -R system.log exceptional.log debug.log

Answer (score 0):

rm rf var/log/* 
what you need to do is just delete log files.